# wrong number or types of arguments in call (while calling a procedure/function)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

If I want to catch this error using exception handling, what are the things that I need to take care of?

> wrong number or types of arguments in call (while calling a
>   procedure/function)

I trying was in different way. Could you please explain.  I have a function:

```
create or replace function test5(v varchar2) return varchar as
begin
  execute immediate 'begin sweet.g:=:v;end;'
  using in v;
  return sweet.g;
exception
when others then 
  return sqlcode||' '||sqlerrm;
end test5;
```

And a package spec and body:

```
create or replace package SWEET as
  function c ( v varchar2,V2 VARCHAR2) return varchar2;
  g varchar(100);
end;
/

create or replace package body SWEET as
  function c(v varchar2, V2 varchar2) return varchar2 as
  begin
    return v||'hi'|| V2;
  end c;
end; 
/
```

when I execute the statement below, I was not able to catch 'wrong number or type of arguments'

```
select test5(sweet.c(,'hello')) from dual;
```

Comment: The function won't compile due to: `PLS-00201: identifier 'SWEET.G' must be declared`.  You would need to declare it in the function.  How are you executing the `select` statement?  Are you just running the single query or is it in a pl/sql block?  When I try it I get `SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression.`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get most of the answers in the PL/SQL manual, but when you are trying to trap an error that isn't one of the predefined ones you have to do something like:

```
DECLARE
   deadlock_detected EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(deadlock_detected, -60);
BEGIN
   ... -- Some operation that causes an ORA-00060 error
EXCEPTION
   WHEN deadlock_detected THEN
      -- handle the error
END;
```

replacing -60 with your actual error, and `deadlock_detected` with whatever you wish to call it.

Comment: That's because you aren't actually running if you get a PLS error. :)
If you are using dynamic code then you could catch it, I show a -6550 when I try it. You would have to rummage through `SQLERRM` and find the `PLS-00306` if you really only want to catch that.

Comment: My point is that if you call a proc inside your BEGIN block and you don't supply enough arguments you're not going to end up in your EXCEPTION block.

Comment: Correct, in terms of a compiled language it would be a compile time error, not a run time error.
Hence my indication that one must use dynamic code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a procedure that takes in two numbers as arguments and outputs them:

```
create procedure testProc (p_param1 in number, p_param2 in number) is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('params: ' || p_param1 || ' ' || p_param2);
end;
```

If you execute this:

```
begin
  testProc(13,188);
end;
```

You get output of: `params: 13 188`

If you do this:

```
begin
  testProc(13);
exception when others then
  dbms_output.put_line('SQLERRM: ' || SQLERRM);
end;
```

You get an error: `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TESTPROC'`

To prevent this and catch the error, you can use dynamic SQL:

```
declare
  v_sql varchar2(50);
  v_result number;
begin
  v_sql := 'begin testProc(13); end;';
  execute immediate v_sql into v_result;
exception
when others then
  dbms_output.put_line('SQLERRM: ' || SQLERRM);
end;
```

That will execute, and the error message will be displayed to dbms_output.  In the `when others then` block you can write any logic you want for what should happen at that point.